# Dart Polymer: Creating PaperDialog with CoreAnimatedPages displayed incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, dart, polymer

I use Dart Polymer PaperDialogs containing CoreAnimatedPages. The idea is to have popups in which you can click through multiple option views.

Example repository available at: https://bitbucket.org/neogucky/polymer-dialog-problem/

**DialogView: view.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog_transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_animated_pages.html">

<polymer-element name="test-view">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog id="extendedNode" vertical autoCloseDisabled=true transition="paper-transition-center" opened=true class="noTitle">
      <content> 
      <core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" valueattr="id" transitions="hero-transition cross-fade">
            <section id="0">
                <br><br>
                <p cross-fade>Click next to see the secret text.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="1">
                <br><br>
                <p cross-fade >This text is a secret, so don't tell Firefox users!</p>
          </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
    </content>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

<script type="application/dart" src="view.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**CSS-file:**

```
html /deep/ paper-dialog {
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

html /deep/ paper-dialog /deep/ core-animated-pages{
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

**Expected behavior:** Upon page load a 300px x 600px dialog should popup with a button at the bottom left.

**Behavior in Firefox:** A small dialog is shown and resembles the dialog in chrome when there is no size set in the css file.

I would like to confirm if this is my fault for using incorrect CSS hooks or if this seems to be a polymer problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CSS is not inside a Polymer element you need to add the polyfill version of the selectors to make it work on browsers without native shadow-DOM support

```
html paper-dialog,
html /deep/ paper-dialog {
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

html paper-dialog core-animated-pages,
html /deep/ paper-dialog /deep/ core-animated-pages{
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html and https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html for more details

Comment: You are correct, I overlooked the fact, that Firefox doesn't yet support shadow-DOM. Your proposed solution isn't working for me though. As long as I have '/deep/' tags in a CSS-class definition, Firefox will ignore it completely. The only solution that seems to work for me, is to duplicate the entries, which hurts my soul. Is this behavior correct or should I be able to get your CSS solution to work?

Comment: AFAIK Polymer creates shimmed versions of the CSS (at least the simple ones) if the CSS is inside a style tag in a Polymer element (or referenced by a style tag inside a Polymer element). I always use an `app-element` which contains the rest of the application and therefore don't have any styles outside of an element. I think there was a JS method provided by Polymer to apply this shimming to CSS outside Polymer elements but In can't remember the name of the method.

Comment: Here it is https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html#sdcss. Seems you just need to add the `shim-shadowdom` attribute to make Polymer do it for styles outside Polymer elements (`<link rel="stylesheet"  href="main.css" shim-shadowdom>`)